# Problem enabling Brotli support on Apache

Tags: apache2, brotli

I installed Brotli by

```
apt install brotli
```

And enabled brotli module in Apache by:

```
a2enmod brotli
```

And added this line on my vhost config:

```
<IfModule mod_brotli.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/x-icon
</IfModule>
```

But still can't enable on my website.

**What else should I do?**

OS: Ubuntu 18 LTS

Comment: mod_brotli isn't included in the Ubuntu 18 LTS packages. Where did you install it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem, in case anyone have similar issue.

`SetOutputFilter` should be defined before `AddOutputFilterByType`

Here is a working config:

```
<IfModule mod_brotli.c>
    SetOutputFilter BROTLI_COMPRESS
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-brotli
    AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/x-icon
</IfModule>
```